# Word Search Grid code

Tags: string, file, python-3.x, try-catch

For the first part of the program i opened a file which is prompted by the user, then wrote code to read, in turn, each line of the file, remove the newline character and append the resulting string to a list of strings.

After the input is complete the grid should be displayed on the screen. But my code is not working according to the instructions, need help please. Below is the code i have done so far:

```
x = {}
file = input("Enter a filename: ")

try:
    a = open(file)
    with open(file) as a:
            x = [line.strip() for line in a]
    a.close()
except IOError as e:
    print ("File Does Not Exist")
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what isn't working. You have some unnecessary code. Here is a version that works fine for me:

```
# x = {}
file = input('enter a filename')

try:
#    a = open(file)
    with open(file) as a:
            x = [line.strip() for line in a]
    a.close()
except IOError as e:
    print ("File Does Not Exist")

print(x)
```

Note that i have commented out the unnecessary lines and added a print statement so that you can see the contents of x